# Acumatica - Selenium Automation Tests: Failure While Generating Classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, acumatica

I'm currently trying to do some automation tests using Selenium in Acumatica. I'm using [SDK documentation for version: 17.204.0019](http://acumatica-builds.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html?prefix=builds/17.2/17.204.0019/TestSDK/).
When I try to generate wrapper classes as it is described in the documentation, it generates the wrapper classes for only 5 out of 8 pages that is referred in ClassGenerator.exe file:

[image]
After running ClassGenerator.exe command from cmd, it only generates the wrapper classes for the following pages:

CS100000

CS102000

CS202000

GL101000

GL201500

And displays the following error for other files, for instance:

[image]
I know this is a tricky one but any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you see if you navigate to that page that is throwing the error (GL202500) in your browser? You can do that by appending the page id in the url ex: /Main?ScreenId=GL202500

Comment: Based on the error message I would expect it redirects you to a setup screen where you can setup the GL module and once setup is done the page should be accessible by the test suite. However I have never setup Selenium and something else could be the cause of the error.

Comment: Another clue from the error message is that the error could be related to Branches configuration. You can navigate to page CS102000 and make sure all branches are configured properly and their configuration can be saved after modification.

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: Thanks for help. Now I've got a clue how to solve this problem.

Comment: I'm not sure how to configure Branch let's say for Currencies. I searched a lot but didn't find anything useful. Can you give me some advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. There was no data in my company to generate so the demo data was needed. All you have to do is to fill the current company with the demo data in Acumatica ERP Configuration wizard and you're good to go.